# Can I add profile data to a facebook test user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> I have a facebook application that requires user data (specifically location). I am trying to use the test user api but I can't figure out how to add additional info to my test users besides through logging into fb and changing it on the page. Is there a way to do this through the api either through initialization or by using an api call to update a user?

Someone posted this question [here](http://www.quora.com/Can-I-add-profile-data-to-a-facebook-test-user), but there is no answer yet. 
Today I exactly ran into the same problem. I have an application that uses the location information of facebook users and now I'm searching for a way to automate the creation of these users for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn't have any graph api's to update profile information besides their current status.  This includes test users.  You can only set the name, password, and email when you create the user too unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You can now log in as a test user and update any profile information the same as a normal user within your app settings. However, you cannot interact with other users or 'like' pages, etc.

**Section:** Apps > Edit App > Developer Roles

**URL:** `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP_ID_HERE]/roles?ref=nav`

[image: Example of demo app's test users]